# Jinja2 - string variable with a space not reading correctly in classname

Tags: flask, jinja2

I'm having an issue with Jinja2 not rendering the string `'fa fa-tachometer'` correctly into the class name.

Jinja2 renders that string like this:

`<i class={{ icon }}></i>`

into

`<i class="fa" fa-tachometer></i>`,

as shown in the image below the code. I've done space literals but it doesn't fix the problem for me.

```
{% set navigation_bar = [
    ('/dashboard', 'dashboard', 'fa fa-tachometer', 'Dashboard')
] -%}
{% set active_page = active_page|default('dashboard') -%}

{# For each of the sidebar nav items, render an <li> #}
{% for href, id, icon, title in navigation_bar %}
    {{ icon }}
    <li {% if id == active_page %} class="active" {% endif %}>
        <a href="{{ href|e }}">
            <i class={{ icon }}></i>
            <span class="nav-label">{{ title|e }}</span>
        </a>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

[image]

Would love a solution to this. Thank you!

Comment: print the output using python and check whether the `variable` you are passing goes right as you need

Comment: The `{{ icon }}` under the `{% for ... %}` prints out the correct string: `"fa fa-tachometer"`. But, when I do `class={{ icon }}` it does the weird string issue I talked about on the question.

Comment: just see what does this do `<i class="{{ icon }}"></i>`. I have added quotes to variable.

Comment: Your comment works :) wish I could upvote you

Comment: I posted the answer. you can upvote now!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This isn't a problem with Jinja; it's a problem with your HTML. You are telling Jinja to output

```
<i class=fa fa-tachometer></i>
```

(The DOM inspector you are using is adding the quotes, not Jinja. If you view the source HTML, they aren't there.)

You need to put quotes around the value given to `class`

```
<i class="{{ icon }}"></i>
```

Answer (score 6):

This was my comment suggestion . You just want to add double quotes over the `{{ icon }}`.

```
<i class="{{ icon }}"></i>
```